# Crystal Reports on Standard Web Site (Windows Azure)

Tags: azure, crystal-reports, web

I'm testing Windows Azure and I uploaded a Web Site that uses Crystal Reports. I'm using the Standard Web Site plan. Is it possible to use Crystal Reports on that plan? I found some answers but all of them were related to VPN or Cloud services.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is Yes. Long answer is: You need to make sure that a Crystal runtime installer gets included in your web project. You need to create a command that will run the Crystal runtime installer every time an instance starts up with your package. There is a great tutorial [here](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/crystal-reports-on-azure-how-to.html), and another one [here](http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/07/running-crystal-reports-on-windows-azure).

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Thank you Chris for your response. The thing is that I think those tutorials are refered to work under Azure Cloud Services, and I'n using Web Site plan.

Comment: I see.....but that's pretty similar then, you will just need to install the Crystal runtime on the server so that when the site gets a request for the page with the report, the runtime will give the server the ability to, well, serve it up.  ;)

Comment: The tutorials just show you how to deploy the runtime on a cloud service so it gets deployed with your package.

Comment: Thank you Campagnolo, I will try it again

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to install, i have followed all the tutorials, and... i have to say that is not possible.

You only can install Crystal Reports on Cloud or in Virtual Machine, but not on website. There is not tutorial that uses a website, all are with clod services.

I tried to install with bootstrapper.exe (windows azure bootstrapper, because startup task appears not to work in website)  and just get an error saying:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe.log.html' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append) at System.IO.File.CreateText(String path) at Cumulux.BootStrapper.PackageRunner.Start(String fileName, String args, Boolean enableSystemProfile, Boolean block) at Cumulux.BootStrapper.BootStrapperManager.Start(BootStrapperArgs args) at BootStrapper.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure Web Apps is complete PaaS Offering where Developer can completely focus on Productivity , while infrastructure is maintained by Azure and thus it has limitations of not able to modify existing infrastructure including any kind of customer installation.

This result in "unavailability of any kind of crystal installation as well".
However , you can upvote here to make a request for default run time availability :

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/6771442-crystal-reports-in-azure-websites

unfortunately Web app don’t support Crystal Reports. We do support SSRS reporting control for ASP.NET.

to use crystal , try cloud service or Azure VM.

Answer (score 0):

Azure WebSites are very abstracted services intended to avoid any kind of administration of the web server. They are intended to deploy websites that after uploading the folder containing the site with all the sources (.aspx, .cs, .js, .css, bin folder, etc) will run without the need of installing anything on the server or editing the registry or the GAC. They are oriented to modern applications that only have dependencies on the bin folder. So if you need to install something on the server for your application to run well, then I'm afraid you have to try with WebRoles (Cloud Services) and include Startup Tasks for installing Crystal, or use a Virtual Machine with full control.